# Getting counter to return correct number after being recursively called c#

Tags: c#, recursion, blazor

I have a method called clearFiles which can be called recursively if there is sub directories. I have created a counter that will count the number of files that have been deleted. The counter holds the correct number when the function is either called once or called recursively but the toast at the end of the function only returns the correct number when it is not called recursively. Is there anyway I can display the toast and then reset the number of filesCleared? Because it's just returning a 0 when it's called recursively.
From playing around with it for a bit it seems like the toast is getting called after the filesCleared variable is set to 0 which is not what I want.

filesCleared variable:

```
    int filesCleared = 0;
```

clearFiles:

```
public async Task ClearFiles()
    {
        var pathName = FileFilter.PathName;
        FileInfo[] files = SortFiles(pathName);

        try
        {
            if(FileFilter.Filter == "all")
            {
                foreach(var file in files)
                {
                    if(file.Extension == FileFilter.Extension || FileFilter.Extension == "all")
                    {
                        File.Delete(file.ToString());
                        filesCleared++;
                    }

                }
            }

            if(FileFilter.Filter == "date")
            {            
                foreach (var file in files) //regular files
                {
                    if(file.CreationTime < FileFilter.DeleteDate) //based on time
                    {
                        if(file.Extension == FileFilter.Extension || FileFilter.Extension == "all") //based on extension
                        {
                            File.Delete(file.ToString());
                            filesCleared++;
                        }  
                    }

                }
            }

            if(FileFilter.Filter == "number")
            {
                var i = 0;

                for(var j = files.Length-1; j >= 0 ; j--)
                {
                    if(files[j].Extension == FileFilter.Extension || FileFilter.Extension == "all")
                    {
                        if(i++ >= FileFilter.FilesToKeep)
                        {
                            File.Delete(files[j].ToString()); 
                            filesCleared++;
                        }
                    }                        
                }

            }

            if (FileFilter.SubFolders == true) //subfiles (will be called recursively w/ each filter)
            {
                foreach(var subDir in new DirectoryInfo(pathName).GetDirectories())
                {
                    //subDir.Delete(true);
                    FileFilter.PathName = subDir.ToString();
                    ClearFiles();
                    //await ClearFiles(subDir.ToString()); 
                }  

                FileFilter.PathName = pathName; //resets the pathName so it will go back to what it was before the recursion 
            }          
        }
        catch (IOException ioExp)    
        {    
            Console.WriteLine(ioExp.Message);    
            Toast = Toast.Bad();
            logger.LogError(ioExp, "Error Deleting");
        }               

        Toast = Toast.Good(filesCleared + " Files Deleted");

        filesCleared = 0; 
    }
```

Comment: If you try `var msg = $"{filesCleared} Files Deleted"; Toast = Toast.Good(msg); filesCleared = 0;` does it work?

Comment: This is a good time to start learning to write small units (methods) that only do one thing. This method is trying to do too many things at the same time, which is why you find it hard to solve this issue. Although this is not an answer to your question I would highly suggest trying to break it down into smaller methods first.

Comment: @Daevin It still says 0 if it's called recursively

Comment: @Xerillio I could break it into smaller methods but the same problem would still be there. I have the correct value in filesCleared when I get to the Toast line but for some reason the toast does not show up on the screen until after filesCleared has been reset.

Comment: I can't see what `Toast` is or what `Toast.Good(filesCleared + " Files Deleted");` does. But setting `filesCleared = 0` after that line won't change the string passed into the method. Since `Toast.Good` is called within every recursive call it's likely causing the issue. Why do you need to call it in every recursion?

Comment: @Xerillo, I don't need to call the toast recursively, I just need to call it once the the whole method is finished, same with setting the filesCleared variable back to 0. The problem with that Is I dont know where else to put these two lines of code.

Comment: Showing the Toast would be handled better if it were done from wherever the whole process is kicked off. I would structure this a bit differently and have the `ClearFiles` method return a `Task<int>` with the count of files cleared and also take a `int filesCleared = 0` parameter so you can just keep passing it to each recursive call, add to it, and then finally return the final count to the calling method that kicked off the whole process. Then you show the Toast with the file count. Also, your current approach will show both a failure and a success Toast if there is an error.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something once but also want to call a method recursively, you have to split it in two. After trying to simplify your code I get a `ClearFiles` method like this:

```
public void ClearFiles()
{
    var filesCleared = 0;
    try
    {
        filesCleared = DeleteFilesRecursively(FileFilter.PathName, FileFilter);
    }
    catch (IOException ioExp)    
    {    
        Console.WriteLine(ioExp.Message);    
        Toast = Toast.Bad();
        logger.LogError(ioExp, "Error Deleting");
    }               

    Toast = Toast.Good(filesCleared + " Files Deleted");
}
```

Now `Toast.Good` is only called once after all subfolders have been traversed.

Note that `filesCleared` is a **local** variable, since I don't see any point in making it global. That way you also don't need to *reset* it.

The implementation of `DeleteFilesRecursively` could be something like this and could be simplified more if you wanted:

```
private const string All = "all";
private const string FilterByDate = "date";
private const string FilterByNumber = "number";

int DeleteFilesRecursively(string dirPath, SomeFileFilterType fileFilter)
{
    FileInfo[] files = SortFiles(dirPath);
    var deleted = 0;
    var toBeDeleted = files.Where(f => MatchesByExtension(f, fileFilter.Extension));

    if (fileFilter.Filter == FilterByDate)
    {            
        toBeDeleted = toBeDeleted.Where(f => MatchesByDate(f, fileFilter.DeleteDate));
    }
    else if (FileFilter.Filter == FilterByNumber)
    {
        // If your SortFiles method sorted in the other
        // direction this call to Reverse would not be needed.
        toBeDeleted = toBeDeleted.Reverse().Take(fileFilter.FilesToKeep);
    }
    
    foreach (var file in toBeDeleted)
    {
        File.Delete(file.ToString()); 
        deleted++;
    }

    if (fileFilter.SubFolders)
    {
        foreach(var subDir in new DirectoryInfo(dirPath).GetDirectories())
        {
            deleted += DeleteFilesRecursively(subDir.FullName, fileFilter);
        }
    }
    
    return deleted;
}

bool MatchesByExtension(FileInfo file, string extension)
    => file.Extension == extension || extension == All;

bool MatchesByDate(FileInfo file, DateTime deleteDate)
    => file.CreationTime < deleteDate;
```

Note that I also removed your [magic strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string), which could be even better by replacing them with an enum type.

I haven't tested this but I believe it should give you the same behavior as your current code (at least the parts about filtering and deleting).